# o:validateBean method="validateCopy" does not validate inputs in composite component

Tags: jsf, el, bean-validation, composite-component, omnifaces

I'm facing a problem using OmniFaces 2.1 o:validateBean with method="validateCopy" when my inputs are composite components. With method="validateActual", it validates as expected.

JSF implementation: Mojarra 2.2.8-jbossorg-1.

My composite component source:

```
<composite:interface>
    <composite:attribute name="target" />
    <composite:attribute name="label"/>
    <composite:attribute name="value" />
    <composite:attribute name="required" />
    <composite:attribute name="size" />
    <composite:attribute name="disabled" />
    <composite:attribute name="styleInput" required="false" />
    <composite:editableValueHolder name="input" targets="input" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="change" event="change" targets="input" />
    <composite:clientBehavior name="keypress" event="keypress" targets="input" />
</composite:interface>

<composite:implementation>
    <p:outputLabel id="label" for="input" value="#{cc.attrs.label}" />
    <h:panelGrid columns="3">
        <p:inputText id="input" value="#{cc.attrs.value}" 
          style="#{cc.attrs.styleInput}" size="#{cc.attrs.size}"
          disabled="#{cc.attrs.disabled}" required="#{cc.attrs.required}">
        </p:inputText>
        <p:message for="input" display="icon">
          <p:effect type="pulsate" event="load" delay="500" />
        </p:message>
    </h:panelGrid>
</composite:implementation>
```

I tracked down to the omnifaces source and got to the source point below, in the o:validateBean:

```
ValueReference valueReference = getValueReference(context.getELContext(), valueExpression);

if (valueReference.getBase().equals(base)) {
    operation.run((EditableValueHolder) component, valueReference);
}
```

In a case where I use a simple input text, the valueReference().getBase() returns my to be validated bean. In a case where I use a composite component, the valueReference().getBase() returns a reference to CompositeComponentAttributesELResolver.ExpressionEvalMap.

Is threre a way to change my composite component so that it works with o:validateBean?

Comment: This has to be fixed from OmniFaces side on. I created https://github.com/omnifaces/omnifaces/issues/155.

Comment: @BalusC, thank you! I'm watching the issue on github to test it when it's time!

Comment: I can't reproduce it based on the information provided so far. Can you please leave feedback on the issue?

Comment: Hi, I am observing same/similar thing using wf 10 and of 2.3....I added content to github  issue.